# Consolidate several lines of a CSV file with firewall rules, in order to parse them easier?

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have a CSV file, which I created using an HTML export from a Check Point firewall policy.
Each rule is represented as several lines, in some cases. That occurs when a rule has several address sources, destinations or services.
I need the output to have each rule described in only one line.
It's easy to distinguish when each rule begins. In the first column, there's the rule ID, which is a number.

Here's an example. In green are marked the strings that should be moved:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmQ2X.jpg

Let me show you an example:

```
NO.;NAME;SOURCE;DESTINATION;SERVICE;ACTION;
1;;fwgcluster;mcast_vrrp;vrrp;accept;
;;;;igmp;;
2;Testing;fwgcluster;fwgcluster;FireWall;accept;
;;fwmgmpe;fwmgmpe;ssh;;
;;fwmgm;fwmgm;;;
```

What I need ,explained in pseudo code, is this:

Read the first column of the next line. If there's a number:
    Evaluate the first column of the next line. If there's no number there, concatenate (separating with a comma) \
    the strings in the columns of this line with the last one and eliminate the text in the current one

The output should be something like this:

```
NO.;NAME;SOURCE;DESTINATION;SERVICE;ACTION;
1;;fwgcluster;mcast_vrrp;vrrp-igmp;accept;
;;;;;;
2;Testing;fwgcluster-fwmgmpe-fwmgm;fwgcluster-fwmgmpe-fwmgm;FireWall-ssh;accept;
;;;;;;
The empty lines are there only to be more clear, I don't actually need them.
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the output you want?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started

```
import csv

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    for r in reader:
        print r
```

EDIT: Given your required output, this should get you nearly there. Its a bit crude but does the majority of what you need. It checks for the 'No.' key and if it has a value it will start a record. If not it will join any other data in the row with the equivalent data in the record. Finally, when a new record is created the old one is appended to the result, this also happens at the end to catch the last item.

```
import csv

result, record = [], None
with open('data2.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    for r in reader:
        if r['NO.']:
            if record:
                result.append(record)
            record = r
        else:
            for key in r.keys():
                if r[key]:
                    record[key] = '-'.join([record[key], r[key]])
    if record:
        result.append(record)

print result
```

Comment: Hi Graeme, thanks!
I tried adapting that code to what I need.
I couldn't make it work.

I'm posting above the pseudocode & how I need the output.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Graeme, thanks again, just before your edit I solved it with the following code.
But you got me looking in the right direction!

If anyone needs it, here it is:

```
import csv 
# adjust these 3 lines 
WRITE_EMPTIES = False 
INFILE = "input.csv"
OUTFILE = "output.csv"
with open(INFILE, "r") as in_file: 
  r = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=";") 
  with open(OUTFILE, "wb") as out_file: 
    previous = None 
    empties_to_write = 0 
    out_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=";") 
    for i, row in enumerate(r): 
      first_val = row[0].strip() 
      if first_val: 
        if previous: 
          out_writer.writerow(previous) 
          if WRITE_EMPTIES and empties_to_write: 
            out_writer.writerows( 
              [["" for _ in previous]] * empties_to_write 
              ) 
            empties_to_write = 0 
        previous = row 
      else: # append sub-portions to each other 
        previous = [ 
          "|".join( 
            subitem 
            for subitem in existing.split(",") + [new] 
            if subitem 
            ) 
          for existing, new in zip(previous, row) 
          ] 
        empties_to_write += 1 
    if previous: # take care of the last row 
      out_writer.writerow(previous) 
      if WRITE_EMPTIES and empties_to_write: 
        out_writer.writerows( 
          [["" for _ in previous]] * empties_to_write 
          )
```